# Adding a timer to the while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

The program I made is like monkey typer and I want to implement a timer into my code but I don't know-how. If I make another while loop it runs separately all I want to do is have a timer running at the same time as you are inputting the words. Where do I implement the timer() the while loop? New while loop?

```
# imports
from words import words
import random
import time


# variables
score = 0
max_score = 10


def timer(length):
    while True:
        print(length)
        length = length - 1
        time.sleep(1)
        if timer == 0:
            print('Game completed \nFinal score, ', score)
            break


while True:
    random_word = random.choice(words)
    print('\n', random_word)
    user = input(':')

# if correct
    if user == random_word:
        score = score + 1
        print('Correct!\n', 'Score,', score)

# if incorrect
    if user != random_word:
        print('Incorrect!\n', 'Score,', score)
        score = score - 1
        if score < 0:
            score = 0
            

# made by Jack Winton
```

Comment: You could try a different approach like `start = time.time()` then once the loop is finished add an `end = time.time()` then do `overall_time = start - end`

Comment: Here's a pointer: store the timestamp at start, run while the current time - timestamp < 30s. That's one monkeytype mode. Or do as @Hunter says.

Comment: Another approach you could use is [multithreading](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multithreading-python-set-1/) or [multiprocesing](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/multiprocessing-in-python), this will allow you to run two tasks at the same time

Comment: @Hunter thanks for the ideas I look into that.

Comment: If these answers helped you can always upvote them

Comment: @hunter i dont have enough reputation :((((

Comment: if I add it as an answer you can upvote it and answer it as correct

Answer (score 0):

You could try using multithreading or multiprocessing to create a timer, have one thread or process working on the code and another thread running the timer. Another option is to use `time = time.time()` then once the loop is finished add an `end = time.time()` and then do `overall_time = start - end` but I think you are trying to do a countdown, not a timer.